# MobileOrg not finding Emacs org file with ssh server

Tags: linux, ssh, emacs, org-mode

I'm just getting starting using `org-mode` with `Emacs` - I thought I'd use it as an alternative to Evernote. Having it on my mobile is pretty important (I'm using the Android version). I'm getting the error:

> Error: 2: No such file

I get this even though the login check worked. I'm using a stock `Emacs` that came with the server distro (NetBSD).

Any ideas about why MobileOrg is not seeing this file even though it is there?

Comment: The problem for you is only on the phone-side, right? Where do you store the files? DropBox?

Comment: As an alternative to Mobileorg, you can also synchronize with Toodledo and use any app on the phone that uses it.  It takes some configuration to get it to your liking.  I am presently using it for my business calendaring purposes and am happy with it.  https://github.com/christopherjwhite/org-toodledo

Comment: The index.org file is on a server that I have, that I'm trying to access through ssh - there is a test connection, which it passes, but for some reason, it won't see the index.org file. I am looking to use dropbox as an alternative to handle this, but am checking out whether dropbox is allowed on the server (it's a community server).

Comment: @Adam, did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem (Mobileorg on Cyanogenmod, over SSH to Ubuntu Server).  SSH works fine, test connection works fine, but Mobileorg fails with Error 2.

Comment: I've also emailed the Mobileorg author and asked for assistance with this issue.  If he replies to me rather than here, I'll forward it on ... fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this very same problem, and I understood how to set up the ssh correctly using the instruction from the following site:

http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/main/3bits/mobile_org_3bits.txt

In sum, you should NOT create index.org manually. You should use `M-x org-mobile-push` to do so. But to use org-mobile-push you have to configure the variables: `org-mobile-directory` and `org-mobile-inbox-for-pull`.

For example, on my setup I did as follows:

```
(setq org-mobile-directory (concat org-directory "/mobile/"))
(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull (concat org-directory "/index.org"))
```